# Keeping website open with Python Requests?

Tags: python, http, header, python-requests

I am just trying to figure out how I can keep the connection to a website open. I tried using a while loop, after I get the URL, but I can see that it is not connected to the website anymore. How can I navigate to a URL, and just keep that URL open entire time while running a loop? I just want it to loop forever, maybe print some data from the website. Here is the code I tried and thanks for any help!

```
import requests
import time

url = 'https://www.google.com'

s = requests.session()

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'}

r = s.get(url, headers=headers)

while True:
    print str(r)
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: What do you mean, 'keep open'? Establish a TCP connection?

Comment: Just like you would normally go to a website. For example, if you went to stackoverflow.com and just kept it open. That is what I am trying to achieve. I want to go a website and just keep it open, just like you were using a normal browser. Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: No, that does not make sense. What do you suppose is happening when you 'keep a website open' in your browser?

Comment: It makes no sense at all. There is no such thing as opened connection in HTTP. When you keep site open by browser you just send request, get response and then look at this response. No matter how long you look, there is no connection between you and site anymore.

Comment: What if I keep searching for a certain text and then print that text out? Or is there just no way to have a open connection like you would in a normal browser?

Comment: I think you missunderstood some conceptions and doing it all wrong. What do you want to achive?

Comment: I tried seeing if there was a way to private message but I don't think I can. Do you have Skype? I can give you my Skype name.

Comment: To provide a counterpoint: unless I missed something, Stackoverflow uses websockets, which do effectively stay open for as long as your browser is open (or at least a lot longer than a normal http connection); with that said, you really need to explain what you're trying to do better with a bit more of an example

Comment: @Foon it is kinda complicated, you got Skype? Add me antfuentes87 and I can explain :) thanks!

Comment: Nope, no skype here; suggest trying to come up with the simplest explanation above (but first you might want to read how http requests normally work etc.)

Comment: Google hangouts? Or any kind of chat? I think I got a better understanding of HTTP now but I am unsure how to give a example of what I'm trying to do. If you have anyway to chat let me know, maybe after I talk it out I will be able to ask the question better. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What is the purpose of your question? What are you trying to achieve by holding open a connection?

I doubt that you can keep it open forever, but what you are doing should work, to some extent.

Using a `requests` session should ensure that the HTTP keepalive option is set appropriately, and the remote server should keep the TCP connection open after servicing each HTTP request. If you stop sending requests, then the server will eventually timeout the connection and close it.

The important point is that you must keep making requests, for example:

```
import requests
import time

url = 'https://www.google.com'

s = requests.session()
while True:
    r = s.get(url)
    print(r.text)
    time.sleep(10)
```

This code should keep the connection open and allow multiple requests to be sent over the same TCP connection.

Comment: In the example you gave me, it would keep going to that URL, over and over? Every time it goes to the URL,  it would be like refreshing the page correct? I need to be able to keep it open, without navigating to the URL over and over. Now maybe after a hour or something, I can reset the connection and go to the URL? But for at least a hour it needs to keep the website open.

Comment: @antfuentes87:  Yes, it would go there over and over. You won't be able to keep the connection open without making subsequent requests. The remote server is not going to hold its connections open forever, why should it waste its resources to do that? You had best provide a reason for why you think that you need to do this - perhaps an alternative solution can be suggested.

Comment: You got Skype by any chance? Add me antfuentes87, it would be 100x easier to explain the whole situation. Thanks!

Comment: You can not do what you want to do. It is not possible with HTTP. That is not how HTTP works. The closest you can get is what I have showed you already. In order to keep the connection open you need to use it, otherwise the remote server will closing the connection rather than waste its resources on you.

Comment: @antfuentes87 mhawke is 100% right, this is not how HTTP works

Comment: Well I am open to other ideas, hit me up on Skype antfuentes87 if you can, I would like to explain the situation.

Answer (score 0):

So this is in general what happens when you send a HTTP request, you create a socket that is connected to the server's one and you send a request and that's all (ok, in reality no but you get it) :).
Then server will reply to you whit a status code (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes), so maybe you want to monitorate a server and see if it is on, for how long and so on. Then you can do this:

```
import requests
import time

your_header = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'}

while 1:
    r = requests.request("GET","http://www.google.com",headers=your_header)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        print("It's on!")
    else:
        break
    time.sleep(2)
```

Very easy, you just send a request every 2 seconds. Then you check if the status code is the correct one. I hope this will help.

Comment: How would I set my headers with the way you are doing it?

Comment: @antfuentes87 do you need them?

Comment: @antfuentes87 look at the edit

Comment: Yeah I tried it that way you now have in your example, but still does not work :( I don't think the website is actually staying open.

Comment: Wait! You are doing a HTTP request, that means: you are sending something and the server will answer. Now the server can go off-line even if there are some requests that are not answered. Basically is like if you call me on my phone, it can be off, i can be in the shower ...

Comment: Yeah that is what I am gathering from this... hmm guess have to figure out another way. If you have Skype add me antfuentes87 and I can explain the whole scenario. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe tomorrow :) I'm a little bit sick now

Comment: All good, thanks for all your help! Guess time to go back to square one lol

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102854/discussion-between-antfuentes87-and-francesco).